# Create a Lambda Expression With 3 conditions

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

I want to create a lambda expression dynamically for this:

```
(o => o.Year == year && o.CityCode == cityCode && o.Status == status)
```

and I write this:

```
var body = Expression.AndAlso(
               Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Year"),
                    Expression.Constant(year)
               ),
               Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "CityCode"),
                    Expression.Constant(cityCode)
               )
               ,
               Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status"),
                    Expression.Constant(status)
               )
           );
```

but for this chunk of code:

```
Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status"),
                    Expression.Constant(status)
                )
```

I got an error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression' to 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'

How I can add 3 conditions to a lambda expression?

Comment: what is `Status` ?

Comment: @MongZhu I Update Ques. Please see it again

Comment: `AndAlso` is a `BinaryExpression`, i.e. has 2 operands. If you have more than 2, you have to chain multiple `AndAlso`, i.e. `AndAlso(AndAlso(op1, op2), op3)` etc.

Comment: You need `status` in lower case for the variable? Now you are passing `Status` type?

Comment: @ArghyaC I Update My Ques...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Expression.AndAlso` takes two expressions. There is an overload that takes three arguments, but that third argument is a `MethodInfo` of a method that implements an *and* operation on the two operands (there are further restrictions in the case of `AndAlso` as it doesn't allow the details of truthiness to be overridden, so the first operand will still need to either have a `true` and `false` operator or be castable to `bool`).

So what you want is the equivalent of:

```
(o => o.Year == year && (o.CityCode == cityCode && o.Status == status))
```

Which would be:

```
var body = Expression.AndAlso(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Year"),
        Expression.Constant(year)
    ),
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "CityCode"),
            Expression.Constant(cityCode)
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status"),
            Expression.Constant(status)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no method called Expression.AndAlso which can take 3 Expressions as arguments.

Please refer below links,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382914(v=vs.110).aspx