# Convert List.Contains to Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Related To:

[Create a Lambda Expression With 3 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032599/create-a-lambda-expression-with-3-conditions)

[Convert Contains To Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388971/convert-contains-to-expression-tree)

In the following of my previous question I faced with this query that I want to write `Expression Tree` version:

```
List<byte?> lst = new List<byte?>{1,2};
from a in myTbl
where a.Age = 20 && lst.Contains(a.Status)
select a
```

I write this code:

```
List<byte?> lst = new List<byte?>{1,2};
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
var body = Expression.AndAlso(
               Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Age"),
                    Expression.Constant(20)
               ),
               Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status"),
                                   "Contains",
                                   Type.EmptyTypes, 
                                   Expression.Constant(lst)));

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
return lambda;
```

and I get the error:

> "No method 'Contains' exists on type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Byte]'."

Please help me to find the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have switched two arguments to `Expression.Call`, your code is trying to create the nonsensical expression `o.Status.Contains(lst)`.

You need to switch the two arguments around:

```
Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(lst),
    "Contains",
    Type.EmptyTypes, 
    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status"))
```

This is assuming that the LINQ provider you're using understands `List<T>.Contains()`. If you need `Enumerable.Contains()`, then have a look at Ivan Stoev's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The difference from [Convert Contains To Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388971/convert-contains-to-expression-tree) is that there we were calling a `string` **instance** `Contains` method, while here we need to call a **static** generic method [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TSource value
)
```

It can be achieved by using another [`Expression.Call overload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Type type,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

like this:

```
// Enumerable.Contains<byte?>(lst, a.Status)
var containsCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), // type
    "Contains", // method
    new Type[] { typeof(byte?) }, // generic type arguments (TSource)
    Expression.Constant(lst),  // arguments (source)
    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status")  // arguments (value)
);
```