# Create Expression Tree For Selector

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Related To :

[Create a Lambda Expression With 3 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032599/create-a-lambda-expression-with-3-conditions)

[Convert Contains To Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388971/convert-contains-to-expression-tree)

[Convert List.Contains to Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620525/convert-list-contains-to-expression-tree)

Please consider above questions.

I want to write a query for this:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
     var DbSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
     var Max = DbSet.Where(exp).Select(selector).Max();
}
```

I don't know how to write a code for `selector`. What `Select` overload I should use? and How I can write that using Expression Tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What Select overload I should use?

[The one with a single parameter in addition to the source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector
)
```

> How can I write that using Expression Tree?

Selector needs to take a `TSource` parameter, and produce the field of which you want to retrieve the `Max`. For example, let's say `TSource` is of type `Employee`, and you want to find the `Max` of its `Salary` property of type `decimal`. Then you would create an expression tree like this:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee));
var m = Expression.Property(p, "Salary");
var e = Expression.Lambda(m, p);
var selector = (Expression<Func<Employee,decimal>>)e;
```