# Create Lambda Expression Selector For New Class Using Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, c#-6.0

Related To:

[Create Expression Tree For Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645185/create-expression-tree-for-selector)

[Create a Lambda Expression With 3 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032599/create-a-lambda-expression-with-3-conditions)

[Convert Contains To Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388971/convert-contains-to-expression-tree)

[Convert List.Contains to Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620525/convert-list-contains-to-expression-tree)

I want to Create `Selector` expression using `Expression Tree` for new class. Please Consider this code:

```
s => new Allocation
     {
         Id = s.Id,
         UnitName = s.UnitName,
         Address = s.NewAddress,
         Tel = s.NewTel
      }
```

I have big class (`MyClass`) that I want to select some of it's Properties. But I want to create it dynamically. How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: You link to a (seemingly random) variety of how expressions can be used. But I'm sure there are more specific ones that exactly tackle your problem.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes you are right, but I don't want to repeat answers to these type of questions: "Why you want dynamic Expression?", "Why You want to create expression using `Expression Tree`, ...

Comment: I don't see how the links answer these questions should anyone feel inclined to ask them (which I'm not). I'm only trying to say that there are must be exact duplicates of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to approach this is to write the equivalent code, then decompile it. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowMeTheLambda<Foo, Allocation>(s => new Allocation
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            UnitName = s.UnitName,
            Address = s.NewAddress,
            Tel = s.NewTel
        });
    }
    static void ShowMeTheLambda<TFrom, TTo>(Expression<Func<TFrom, TTo>> lambda)
    { }
}
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    public string NewTel { get; set; }
    public string NewAddress { get; set; }
}
class Allocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I compile this and decompile it with "reflector", I get:

```
private static void Main()
{
    ParameterExpression expression;
    MemberBinding[] bindings = new MemberBinding[] { Expression.Bind((MethodInfo) methodof(Allocation.set_Id), Expression.Property(expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "s"), (MethodInfo) methodof(Foo.get_Id))), Expression.Bind((MethodInfo) methodof(Allocation.set_UnitName), Expression.Property(expression, (MethodInfo) methodof(Foo.get_UnitName))), Expression.Bind((MethodInfo) methodof(Allocation.set_Address), Expression.Property(expression, (MethodInfo) methodof(Foo.get_NewAddress))), Expression.Bind((MethodInfo) methodof(Allocation.set_Tel), Expression.Property(expression, (MethodInfo) methodof(Foo.get_NewTel))) };
    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { expression };
    ShowMeTheLambda<Foo, Allocation>(Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, Allocation>>(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(Allocation)), bindings), parameters));

}
```

Note: `memberof` and `methodof` don't actually exist in C# - you can either manually get the method infos via reflection, or use `Expression.PropertyOrField`. We can thus rewrite it as:

```
ParameterExpression expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "s");
MemberBinding[] bindings = new MemberBinding[]
{
    Expression.Bind(typeof(Allocation).GetProperty(nameof(Allocation.Id)), Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, nameof(Foo.Id))),
    Expression.Bind(typeof(Allocation).GetProperty(nameof(Allocation.UnitName)), Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, nameof(Foo.UnitName))),
    Expression.Bind(typeof(Allocation).GetProperty(nameof(Allocation.Address)), Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, nameof(Foo.NewAddress))),
    Expression.Bind(typeof(Allocation).GetProperty(nameof(Allocation.Tel)), Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, nameof(Foo.NewTel))),
};
ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { expression };
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, Allocation>>(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(Allocation)), bindings), parameters);
```

Comment: God knows how many time I refresh this page to see an answer.Thank you Mr. Gravell. You are great. I will test it tomorrow and I will say the result.

Comment: But for my knowledge what reflector you used? You give it the assembly or class? How you get that result?

Comment: @Arian note I've updated the code; here's reflector doing the hard work - load the assembly, find the method (`Main` in this case) and select "decompile": https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ZEX.png

Comment: Great Great Great

Comment: Thx to @MarcGravell. I didn't know about this decompile "Trick". Thats a really nice approach! Have to try this by myself.