# Create Where Clause Dynamically For Byte? Field

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, c#-7.0

Related To: [Create a Lambda Expression With 3 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032599/create-a-lambda-expression-with-3-conditions)

Exactly similar to above topic I wrote this `Expression`:

```
var body = Expression.AndAlso(
Expression.Equal(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Year"),
    Expression.Constant(year)
    ),
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "CityCode"),
            Expression.Constant(cityCode)
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Status"),
            Expression.Constant(50)
        )
    )
);
```

the only different is in my new table `Status` is `tinyint null` or `(byte?)` in `C#`. When I run the code I got this error:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Byte]' and 'System.Byte'

so I change `Expression.Constant(50)` to `Expression.Constant((byte?)50)` and again got the same error. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

---

Update 1)

I tried this: `Expression.Constant(50, typeof(byte?));` but I got this error:

> Argument types do not match

Comment: Have you tried: `Expression.Constant(50, typeof(byte?));`?

Comment: Yes and I got this error: `Argument types do not match`

Comment: Which call exactly throw the exception?

Comment: @PetSerAl, All those calls!

Comment: @Arian It is not possible. Since you do not have any exception handlers here, once first method call throw the exception, other method calls will not be done. So that exactly one method call throw the exception. Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost as Evan said:

```
Expression.Constant((byte?)50, typeof(byte?))
```